# Arrays to store hex values

Tags: arduino

I am actually working on implementing a IR learning and transmitting IR code. Currently using arduino uno.  I want to store an array of hex values which is read by the IR receiver connected to the arduino and then display it on the serial monitor for the time being. The problem is when I create a variable using unsigned long var, it works fine but when I make it an array eg.  Unsigned long code[50] . It gives a compilation error. Can someone help me out with this...
Thanks

Comment: It would GREATLY help if you write the compilation error....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

uint32_t arr[4] = {0x5,0x6,0x7,0x8};

Comment: What is this answer's point? The OP already wrote that when he writes `Unsigned long code[50]` he has a problem.. So he obviously knows how to make an array (apart from the capital U). So were you suggesting using the alias instead of the complete type? Were you just writing how to write an array without reading the original question? Were you... Well, explain what is the error and why this corrects it. And... You should definitely use the code tag, like someone edited and you revert the edit

Comment: First, he didn't write its compilation error. I understood that he just don't know how to initialize the array with hex number